# Spring Rest Service Call returning error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty

Tags: java, rest, google-chrome, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I wrote a REST Call which will return health status when called

```
 @RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/account")
public class HealthCheckController {

    protected final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @RequestMapping(value = "/health", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "application/json" })
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Returns the health status of the application", notes = "Load balancer user this to confirm the health of the node")
    public @ResponseBody String getHealth(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        log.info("***" + RequestCorrelation.getId() + "***" + "HealthCheckController - getHealth () Called");

        return "{\"health\":{\"SERVICES\":\"OK\"}}";
    }

}
```

When I open this in swagger or postman it returns proper response. But when i hit this URL in chrome browser i am seeing

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

Why so? and how to fix this?

Comment: hi shiva i have also got the same issue it was working on local but on server it stopped can you tell me was the issue was related to Apache Server

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue. Have an object with the following class annotations and method:

@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})

```
@GET
@Path("version")
public String getVersion() { return "v1"; }
```

Added MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN to the end of the @Produces annotation. Didn't work.
Moved it the beginning of the @Produces annotation. Didn't work.

Moving/Adding it to the method resolved the issue for me. Your client will need to be able to accept that media type as well.

```
@GET
@Path("version")
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
public String getVersion() { return "v1"; )
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

In your `getHealth()` method, you're returning a String but in your `@RequestMapping` annotation, you specify that your method will produce JSON.

Try one of these:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/health", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "text/plain" })
 //Now, pass Accept = "text/plain" in the request header:
```

or

```
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
  public List<String> getHealth(..) {
      /*
...

     */
   
            ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList();
            list.add("Health OK");
            return list;

  
  }
```

This would give you
`["Health OK"]` in the response.

Answer (score -1):

Try to return not a String but

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(yourString, HttpStatus.OK);
```

and also change this

```
public @ResponseBody String getHealth(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
```

to this

```
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> getHealth(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
```

And if it doesn't work, try to add .xml or .json to the end of your URL, when you accessing it in browser.